# mtime difference of microseconds

Tags: filesystems, rsync, timestamps

The following file

```
$ stat Louis-Jens-Kusi.jpg 
  File: Louis-Jens-Kusi.jpg
  Size: 183455          Blocks: 360        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 824h/2084d      Inode: 4720932     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    kusi)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2018-08-31 14:57:51.312217016 +0200
Modify: 2018-08-31 14:57:51.980205978 +0200
Change: 2018-08-31 14:57:51.980205978 +0200
 Birth: 2018-08-31 14:57:51.312217016 +0200
```

was synced to Google Drive, then back to another machine, where I get the following stats

```
$ stat Louis-Jens-Kusi.jpg 
  File: Louis-Jens-Kusi.jpg
  Size: 183455          Blocks: 360        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 549554      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    kusi)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2021-11-03 11:03:18.172433137 +0100
Modify: 2018-08-31 14:57:51.980000019 +0200
Change: 2021-11-03 11:03:18.169278278 +0100
 Birth: 2021-11-03 11:03:04.089473196 +0100
```

The mtime differs by ~0.2ms. How is that possible?

I use rsync based backup mechanism which relies on mtime. rsync now considers the files different, which is an issue for my backup process

Comment: There were at least three different file systems involved in the transfer from the original system, though Google drive, then to the destination system, all likely with different capabilities.  Interestingly enough, the file on the destination system has a birth date years after its modification date...  FWIW, this seems a bit like measuring the distance between Paris and Berlin to the meter and finding two different measurements differed by three meters.

Comment: Surely one JPG file isn't going to ruin your backup strategy?

Comment: Capture an [`mtree`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree) specification of the file system before you transfer it.  Then after you transfer back to the second machine, you can use the `mtree` specification to verify that your files transfered correctly, plus you can reset any stray time/ownership/permission attributes.

Comment: @JeremyBoden I can cope with one file :) However it looks like EVERY file has a changed mtime. In my case, this means sending 50gb of data to the backup drive. But I guess storage is too cheap to worry about an additional useless 50gb

Comment: Doesn't `rsync --checksum` alter the file-times-and-sizes check, so that it ignores times and examines only sizes. Files with the same size are checksummed with MD5(?) in rsync and only the mismatches are transferred.